C# clicking button on Excel worksheet
I have developed an Excel workbook that is being used by C# developers. When someone using Excel clicks on one of two OptionButtons, an underlying cell ("B1") value changes (1<->2). Based on that cell value, one range becomes "active" (black text, and values are added to totals), while the opposite OptionButton range becomes "inactive" (gray text, values are ignored).
If I manually change the value in B1, the OptionButtons react accordingly (when I input '2' into B1, OptionButton 2 is filled and OptionButton 1 is cleared), and the ranges also react as described above. So far, so good.
But when their C# code opens the workbook and changes the value of "B1", saves and closes the workbook, the change is ignored. It's as if, when opening the spreadsheet, Excel notices the button control states don't match the linked cell range, and decides the stored button states should be followed. The value of B1 is overwritten to match the state of the buttons.
The easiest path, to me, is to use C# to click the OptionButton, instead of changing B1. I can open and access the spreadsheet, but I can't find a way to click a control inside that C#-controlled instance of Excel.
I'm also open to any other solution.

OK, I think I found two solutions.
One is very klugey: I assign a master control range (B2, for example). B2 is normally empty. If on Document_Open B2 contains 1 or 2 (the legal values), then B1 is reset to B2's value, and B2 is cleared (""). I hide B2' value from the users, and password-protect it. Like I said: klugey.
Or, #2: write some code that changes the control cell B1, but DOESN'T suffer from their "revert to button value" problem. In short, I suspect these programmers' code is the real problem here.

Does your VBA code rely on events? Have they disabled events when opening the workbook??

Good question, @MacroMarc. Nope, the button and its control cell are not tied together with VBA.
